# Given two files, I want to compare the data and print those lines that match by using hashing in Perl

Tags: perl

suppose i have two file:
file 1:

```
a aa
a bb
b vv
c nn
c nn
```

file 2:

```
a +
b -
c +
```

ouput should be :

```
 a aa : +
 a bb : +
 b vv : -
 c nn : +
 c nn : +
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading `file2` first and feeding key/value pairs into `%h` hash. After that reading `file1` and adding sign at the end of line from `%h` hash,

```
perl -lane'
  BEGIN { $x=shift; %h = map +split, <>; @ARGV=$x }
  print $_, " : ", $h{$F[0]}
' file1 file2
```

output

```
a aa : +
a bb : +
b vv : -
c nn : +
c nn : +
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for Perl, just use `join(1)`:

```
$ join file1 file2
a aa +
a bb +
a cc +
b vv -
c nn +
c nn +
```

If you really need the colon, add it using awk or so.